# Bootstrap-datepicker embedded inline mode not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, embed, inline, bootstrap-datepicker

I have successed to make the datepicker work in text mode with the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({});
  });
</script>


<input type="text" id="mydatepicker">
```

However, when I switch to the embedded/inline mode with the following code, there's no anything on the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link href="css/datepicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#mydatepicker').datepicker({});
  });
</script>


<div id="mydatepicker"> </div>
```

As demonstrated [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#inline-or-embedded), "Instantiating the datepicker on a simple div will give an embedded picker that is always visible."

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error on console?

Comment: @SreelalPMohan Well, it's said "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined". When I add '$("#datepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {});' into the script. The console has no error any more. But the datepicker still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Weird things happened. I just replaced the datepicker.css and bootstrap-datepicker.js. Now everything works fine.